# Android app: After successfully sending apprequests, friends did not get Notifications

Tags: android, facebook

I sent an **apprequests** through my test Android app and in `onComplete()` method I got message like this

> Bundle[{to[0]=1460762087, request=425924150781914}]

But at friends side, they did not get any notifications. Only at left side, i can see a "1" next to "Apps and Games", but after click, I did not see any app request.

here is my code

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("message", "Join us!");

        context.facebook.dialog(context, "apprequests", params, new DialogListener(){
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values){
                Log.d("send request response", values.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e){
                Log.d("facebook error", e.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e){
                Log.d("dialog error", e.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel(){}
        });
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue, solved it yesterday:

1. Log in to your edit app page on Facebook -
   https://developers.facebook.com/apps
2. Fill the fields for
   `Canvas URL` and `Secure Canvas URL`, even if you add bogus URLs the
   notifications should start appearing properly (as long as the URLs
   end with a '/')
3. Now you'll see that if you click on those notifications on a mobile
   device you'll either get your app opened if it's already installed
   or get to the google play page of your app.
4. If you click on the notification on a desktop browser, you'll get to
       a facebook page which except for a top header is empty, you can fill that
       page with the `Secure Canvas URL`, you'll need a site that supports
       https for that.

Comment: Thanks man! I too can send requests but no notification on the receiving end. when i filled up the canvas urls my friends started to receive my apps request notifaction!