# How to link facebook app request to Android app

Tags: android, facebook-requests

I could open the AppRequestsListener on my app for Android, invite friends and send them an app request. However, that app request never arrived until I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11014002/android-app-after-successfully-sending-apprequests-friends-did-not-get-notific) that you have to tick App on Facebook in your Facebook app settings and enter a bogus-URL in the Canvas URL and Secure Canvas URL fields. I did that and then the notifications were received by the selected facebook-friends correctly.

However, right now upon clicking on the received app request just a blank page opens. whereas I want the app to redirect to [this play store link of my Wingman app](http://bit.ly/PwOczB) directly. From my feeling the most plausible solution would be to include the play store link in the Canvas URL and Secure canvas URL, however that just shows a blank page, too.

I don't understand why I didn't find anything, there must be so many iPhone/Android apps sending requests to facebook friends and then linking to the app store.